# Load only first few .XML files (e.g. 10 xmls) from directory containing 100 files in Pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-xml

I want to load the first 10 XML files in each iteration from a directory containing 100 files and remove that XML file that has already read, to another directory.

what I have tried so far in pyspark.

```
li = ["/mnt/dev/tmp/xml/100_file/M800143.xml","/mnt/dev/tmp/xml/100_file/M8001422.xml"]
df1 = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag","Quality").load(li) 
df1.show()
```

But I am getting an error : IllegalArgumentException: 'path' must be specified for XML data.

Is there is any way to read files after storing the full path of XML files inside the list?
Or please suggest another approach.